# Convert text to date/timestamp in a matrix in R for plot.ts

Tags: r

I have a matrix with value and timestamps as strings.

```
> m
        value time
   [1,] 0     "2014-10-20T01:48:00.019+02:00"
   [2,] 0     "2014-10-20T01:48:30.019+02:00"
   [3,] 0     "2014-10-20T01:49:00.019+02:00"
   [4,] 0     "2014-10-20T01:49:30.020+02:00"
   [5,] 0     "2014-10-20T01:50:00.020+02:00"
...
```

I would like to convert the strings to timestamps or so, to plot them on a timeseries chart (I suggest to use plot.ts!?). I knew that I can use

```
strptime(data, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

to convert the string, but I don't knew how to apply to the matrix.

**Background:**

I loaded data from a JSON file:

```
{
measurements:
  0:  {
    id: "87144000"
    self: "http://xxxyyyzzz.com/measurement/measurements/87144000"
    source: {...}
    time: "2014-10-20T01:48:00.019+02:00"
    type: "LightSensor"
    LightSensor: {
        light: {
          unit: "LUX"
          value: 0
        }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I loaded and transform:

```
> l <- fromJSON(file = "./dev/learning-r/data/c8y-measurement-light.json")
> m <- lapply (l$measurements, function(x) c(x$LightSensor$light['value'], x['time']))
> m <- do.call(rbind, m)

> str(m)
List of 2000
 $ : num 0

 ...

 $ : num 0
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 1000 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "value" "time"
```

Thanks!

Comment: you looking for `m$time <- as.POSIXTct(m$time, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")`?

Comment: Do you have a `matrix` or a `data.frame`? Please provide `str(m)`

Comment: Thanks for comments. str(m) turns out, it is a list.

Comment: @agstudy there is a typo in your comment, as it should be as.POSIXct, not as.POSIX _T_ ct. That did not work, I had to combine with strptime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the structure m is a list. I converted the list to a data.frame

```
dat <- data.frame(m)
```

Now I can apply @agtudy slightly changed command

```
dat$time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(dat$time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS"))
```

Results in

```
> dat
     value                time
1        0 2014-10-20 01:48:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
 strptime(x['time'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS");
```

directly in your lapply function. This ignores the timezone for now, but should work. Look at the %z parameter if you interested in the timezone (some regex might be required).

Then convert the matrix to a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(m)
```

Now you should be able to plot the data directly (please check that not all values are zero with `summary(df)`) with plot(df).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use this solution I end up in a List like this:
        value sec    min hour mday mon year wday yday isdst zone   gmtoff
   [1,] 0     0.019  48  1    20   9   114  1    292  1     "CEST" NA

Which is not a good input for plot, resulting in many warnings.